# Disable First Line of a TextBox in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, readonly

How can I disable the first line of a `TextBox` in a WPF application?

Is there a possibility?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the first line of text into a separate disabled control.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to monitor the SelctionChanged event as well as the backspace keydown.  Try something like this.

```
    private void textbox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox1.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(textbox1.SelectionStart) == 0)
            textbox1.SelectionStart = textbox1.GetLineText(0).Length;
    }

    private void textbox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Back && textbox1.SelectionStart == textbox1.GetLineText(0).Length)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```